# How to get string value of current collection_select selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have a `collection_select` which allows a customer to select another customer. I also have a button which, when clicked, should trigger a javascript function that finds the string value of the customer selected, and adds it to a list on the page.

HTML:

```
<%= f.collection_select :id,
                     Customer.where(business_id: current_customer.business_id),
                     :id,
                     :full_name,
                     { prompt: 'Select' },
                     { id: "colleage-select", onChange: "renderColCal(this)" } %>

<button id="click-me" type="button">
    <img  src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-ui-elements/700/07_plus-128.png" alt="Add to Event" style="width: 50px"/>
</button>

<div>
   <p>Meeting Participants:</p>
   <ol id ="list">
   </ol>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function (){
    $("#click-me").click(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var List = document.getElementById('list'); 

        var name = document.getElementById('colleague-select').textContent; //this should get whatever name is currently in the collection_select
        var entry = document.createElement("li");

        entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
        List.appendChild(entry);

        return false;

    });
});
```

However, this is not appending anything to my list. This function is **successful** when I make a test text node, i.e. `entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode("test"));` 
so I know it's a problem with how I'm finding the customer name from the collection_select. **What is the correct way to do this?** Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why using vanilla `javascript` when you already have `jQuery` added to your project.

I would rewrite your `javascript` code this way:

```
$(function (){
    $("#click-me").click(function (e){
        var list = $("#list") ;
        var name = $("#colleague-select option:selected").text() ;
        var entry = "<li>" + name + "</li>" ;

        list.append(entry);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: ok, but wont using .val() on colleague-select get the customer's id instead of their name?

Comment: ok, it is creating the new <li> when clicking the button, but no text is appearing within it

Comment: Well the `javascript` is correct. Verify if the `select` have the `id` **colleague-select**